# Regex Email Validation problem?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am using C# with jQuery to validate a bunch of emails entered into a form.

`public const string Email = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\\\-\\\\.]+)@((\\\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-]+\\\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$";`

This is what I'm using but I seem to be getting wrong entries ? Can anyone assist me ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example "wrong entry" that is improperly validated by your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're double-escaping your backslashes. It's helpful to use the `@` syntax for string declaration to avoid this confusion:

```
public const string Email = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$";
```

You'll be closer without the double-escape:

```
public const string Email = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$";
```

The `\[` after the matched `@` is probably also a mistake, leaving...

```
public const string Email = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$";
```

Comment: aha ! thanks so much - yes this is exactly the problem :) no idea why I got downvoted :(

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) has a great discussion of what regular expression to use for matching email addresses, and the merits of these variants.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the MailAddress class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh392kbs.aspx

Comment: this doesn't prevent test@test from going through, since server to server, this is OK.

Comment: Starting next year test@test will be a legitimate email address. http://www.upi.com/Business_News/2011/06/20/ICANN-approves-dot-changes/UPI-29491308583048/

Answer (score 0):

I used  this. working great :)

```
 /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this dude,

```
public const string Email= "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is regular expression, what i used in my code..all the way tested..and handled every scenario .

```
(([ ]*[A-Za-z0-9]([_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9])*([.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9])*([-]{1}[A-Za-z0-9])*)+\\@([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\.([A-Za-z]{2,4}))[ ]*(((;|,|; | ;| ; | , | ,){1}"+"([ ]*[A-Za-z0-9]([_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9])*([.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9])*([-]{1}[A-Za-z0-9])*)+\\@([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\.([A-Za-z]{2,4}[ ]*))*)[ ]*
```

Comment: What about tld like `museum` or `travel`? And name like `jean-françois`?